# Loading variables into a char[][]

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, constructor, char

Consider the following code:

```
public String keyCompressor(String key) {
    char[][] keyArray = new char[255][255];
    for (int i = 0; i < key.length(); i++) {
        if (key.charAt(i) < 0 || key.charAt(i) > 255) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("" + "Somehow, you made it past the check in the matrix builder, but you wont get past me!");
        }
        keyArray[i][0] = key.charAt(i) + Sorters.getShift(key, i) > 255 ? (char) ((key.charAt(i) + Sorters.getShift(key, i)) - 255) : (char) (key.charAt(i) + Sorters.getShift(key, i));
    }

    return keyArray.toString();
}
```

<strike>I know how to load the variable into the first array, but how would I go about loading a variable into the second array? Also, how would I make the array print out to console where the first array is on the left and the second if on the right?</strike>

Comment: What second array are you talking about? What you have there is an array of arrays of chars. The outer array contains 255 arrays of chars. Each of those 255 arrays contains 255 chars. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What is this class `Sorters`?

Comment: What you have there is a two-dimensional array, or a matrix if you will... You do not have two arrays; if you want two arrays, then you should initialize them like: `char[] arrayOne = new char[255]` and `char[] arrayTwo = new char[255]`

Comment: Also, a char is an unsigned number. There's no way it can ever be < 0.

Comment: Also, if you know that you are using a bi-dimensional array, then you should see that you are only using one element of each array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using a `char[][]` instead of just using two separate `char[]`. Problem solved.